# How to convert from vector<vector<Point>> contours to CVPoint or cvpoint2d32f?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, vector, contour

How to convert from `vector<vector<Point>> contours` to `CVPoint` or `cvpoint2d32f`  ?
`vector<vector<Point>> contours`
`CvPoint cvp` or `cvpoint2d32f   Cvp32`

I have three objects in my contours , i just want to copy to `CvPoint` or `CvPoint2d32F`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy the `i`th vector and `j`th element in it to `CvPoint`:

```
CvPoint p = contours[i][j];
```

If you want to copy to `cvPoint2D32f`:

```
CvPoint2D32f p2 = cvPoint2D32f(contours[i][j].x, contours[i][j].y);
```

---

**P.S.:** Suggestion: `CvPoint` or `CvPoint2d32F` are [old OpenCV APIs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html), you should use new API `Point` or `Point2f` instead.